# What can trigger this unwanted start signal?

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a semi-automatic labelling machine that is malfunctioning in a strange way. Here's how the machine should work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmlPliTG2KY&feature=youtu.be&t=22

I.e.
Pull handle down manually  =>  microswitch closes circuit  =>  start signal to the motor  =>  1 label rolls on and the label roll stops where it should when a sensor detects the label end and sends a stop signal.

But what happens in addition to this is:

Handle lifted up  =>  microswitch opens the circuit  =>  ***another start signal to the motor***  => 1 more label rolls onto the same bottle (and then the label roll stops where it should).

**The big question is: What condition or component could cause this behaviour?**

Everything except for this double start signal works as it should. I tried replacing the microswitch (vendor's only suggestion so far) and also to remove the microswitch and close the circuit by hand with the wires, and the result is the same. So it's not just a faulty switch.

The malfunction was not present when the machine was brand new, but started appearing after a short while. Sometimes, when the machine was just turned on, it would function mostly correctly for fifteen minutes (malfunction only 1 in 15 labels) but then 'degrade' to every time. And now it's every time.

Do you think it would solve the problem if I send the circuitry board back to the vendor and get it replaced?

[image: The circuitry description from the manual.]

[image: The circuitry board.]

[image: The only other visible component.]

[image: Microswitch.]

Comment: Your question will probably be closed as it is a repair question which is off-topic. It sounds like switch contact bounce due to wear to me. You could try adding a 100 nF capacitor across the switch contacts.

Comment: Ok thanks. it's a brand new machine, I've replaced the switch with an extra that came with it but no change. I've removed the switch and maually closed the circuit with the cable ends and when I take them apart the unwanted trigger still happens. So it's not the switches I'd say. Would the 100nF capacitor still be worth a try?

Comment: Touching wires together is likely to be much more bouncy than the switch contacts. I don't know the answer. We don't know whether the switch is mechanical or proximity / photo type. We don't know if your label sensor is in the correct location. We don't know if your speed setting is right. (This is why many of these questions get closed - inadequate troubleshooting.)

Comment: Aha. It's a mechanical switch, I've uploaded a picture of it. The speed is fine and the label sensor (photo type) works properly, i.e. the motor stops after one label as it should. It's the second start signal that is the problem.

Comment: If the machine is brand new there should be some warranty as long as you have not done own repairs. The capacitor idea given earlier can reduce radio interference if a radio transmitter or a high current other device somewhere near triggers the machine. Only having the device in own hands gives a possiblity to make rational fault finding attempts instead of guesses.

Comment: @user287001 I agree.  The only times the motor is triggered are 1) When I pull the handle down (the switch closes the circuit) and 2) When I let the handle back up (the switch opens the circuit). Nevertheless I just tested to turn off electrical nearby equipment and radios and left my phone far away, but no change.